# Создаю 100 сокетов

Tags: java

Есть задача - создать более 100 сокетов (серверов). На каждый из них примерно каждую минуту будут присылаться различного типа файлы, архивы, фотографии. Подскажите, что сделать, чтобы не создавать более 100 вот таких кодов:

```
// -----Этот код в main()
ServerSocket[] sockets = new ServerSocket[100];
// -----

// Вот этот код 100 раз не хочу печатать
public class socket_1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket i1;
        DataInputStream i2;
        while (true) {
            try {
                i1 = sockets[0].accept();
                i2 = new DataInputStream(i1.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(i2.readUTF());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Может, можно чем-то похожим заменить `Thread`? Или как-нибудь чудом разрешить её запуск более одного раза?

Скажу сразу, заменить эту сотню сокетов на что-то другое строго нельзя. Если уж нельзя вообще придумать, то есть полный `nothing` - так и напишите.

Comment: Есть такие штуки - называются циклы))) они и решат вопрос)

Comment: я сильно сомневаюсь, что Вам действительно нужно 100 сокетов на сервере.

Comment: Пока в вашем коде единственное, что изменяется - это индекс сокета в массиве. Передавайте его в качестве параметра в конструктор, или вообще сделайте серверный сокет полем класса. Но выглядит безумненько. Если вы расскажете, чего вы хотите, наши квалифицированные специалисты объяснят вам, почему вам это не нужно.

Comment: Просто собираюсь сделать систему видеонаблюдения. Чатобы всё стало понятно где и куда, то надо весь огромный исходник кидать сюда. Смысла нет. Я просто и сократил, и задал вопрос по конкретной теме.

Comment: @Lesperanza если вы собираетесь создавать систему видеонаблюдения, то я рекомендую вам всю транспортную часть   реализовывать на плюсах. А вообще, учитывая "уровень" вашего вопроса, я рекомендую взять готовое решение, на гитхабе можно найти адекватное решение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы хотите сделать нагрузочный тест. По всей видимости, вы не понимаете, что такое сокет, по этому поясню. Сокет это интерфейс для обеспечения обмена данными между процессами.

То есть если вы создадите множество сокетов, вы попросту создадите множество точек для коммуникации с вашим приложением. В рамках одной программы это лишино смысла чуть менее чем полностью, а чисто технически создаваемый оверхед незначительный, а вот архитектуру усложняет серьезно.

Предполагаю, что на самом деле вам нужен асинхронный сокет сервер. Прилагаю пример:

Сервер:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AsynchronousServerSocketChannel server = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
        .open();
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 8989;
    InetSocketAddress sAddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    server.bind(sAddr);
    System.out.format("Server is listening at %s%n", sAddr);
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    attach.server = server;
    server.accept(attach, new ConnectionHandler());
    Thread.currentThread().join();
  }
}
class Attachment {
  AsynchronousServerSocketChannel server;
  AsynchronousSocketChannel client;
  ByteBuffer buffer;
  SocketAddress clientAddr;
  boolean isRead;
}

class ConnectionHandler implements
    CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Attachment> {
  @Override
  public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel client, Attachment attach) {
    try {
      SocketAddress clientAddr = client.getRemoteAddress();
      System.out.format("Accepted a  connection from  %s%n", clientAddr);
      attach.server.accept(attach, this);
      ReadWriteHandler rwHandler = new ReadWriteHandler();
      Attachment newAttach = new Attachment();
      newAttach.server = attach.server;
      newAttach.client = client;
      newAttach.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
      newAttach.isRead = true;
      newAttach.clientAddr = clientAddr;
      client.read(newAttach.buffer, newAttach, rwHandler);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable e, Attachment attach) {
    System.out.println("Failed to accept a  connection.");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

class ReadWriteHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Attachment> {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, Attachment attach) {
    if (result == -1) {
      try {
        attach.client.close();
        System.out.format("Stopped   listening to the   client %s%n",
            attach.clientAddr);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      return;
    }

    if (attach.isRead) {
      attach.buffer.flip();
      int limits = attach.buffer.limit();
      byte bytes[] = new byte[limits];
      attach.buffer.get(bytes, 0, limits);
      Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
      String msg = new String(bytes, cs);
      System.out.format("Client at  %s  says: %s%n", attach.clientAddr,
          msg);
      attach.isRead = false; // It is a write
      attach.buffer.rewind();

    } else {
      // Write to the client
      attach.client.write(attach.buffer, attach, this);
      attach.isRead = true;
      attach.buffer.clear();
      attach.client.read(attach.buffer, attach, this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable e, Attachment attach) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Клиент:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
    SocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8989);
    Future<Void> result = channel.connect(serverAddr);
    result.get();
    System.out.println("Connected");
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    attach.channel = channel;
    attach.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
    attach.isRead = false;
    attach.mainThread = Thread.currentThread();

    Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    String msg = "Hello";
    byte[] data = msg.getBytes(cs);
    attach.buffer.put(data);
    attach.buffer.flip();

    ReadWriteHandler readWriteHandler = new ReadWriteHandler();
    channel.write(attach.buffer, attach, readWriteHandler);
    attach.mainThread.join();
  }
}
class Attachment {
  AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
  ByteBuffer buffer;
  Thread mainThread;
  boolean isRead;
}
class ReadWriteHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Attachment> {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, Attachment attach) {
    if (attach.isRead) {
      attach.buffer.flip();
      Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
      int limits = attach.buffer.limit();
      byte bytes[] = new byte[limits];
      attach.buffer.get(bytes, 0, limits);
      String msg = new String(bytes, cs);
      System.out.format("Server Responded: "+ msg);
      try {
        msg = this.getTextFromUser();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
        attach.mainThread.interrupt();
        return;
      }
      attach.buffer.clear();
      byte[] data = msg.getBytes(cs);
      attach.buffer.put(data);
      attach.buffer.flip();
      attach.isRead = false; // It is a write
      attach.channel.write(attach.buffer, attach, this);
    }else {
      attach.isRead = true;
      attach.buffer.clear();
      attach.channel.read(attach.buffer, attach, this);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable e, Attachment attach) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  private String getTextFromUser() throws Exception{
    System.out.print("Please enter a  message  (Bye  to quit):");
    BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String msg = consoleReader.readLine();
    return msg;
  }
}
```

Далее, вы сказали, что хотите закидывать сервер различной информацией, файлами, картинками и прочим. Видимо вы упускаете, что все эти файлы не более чем набор байтов. То есть для решения вашей задачи достаточно закидывать сервер просто рандомно сгенерированными наборами байт.